# SQL Import and Export Wizard to SQL Azure DB failing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to move data and schema from a hosted SQL Server 2008 instance to a SQL Azure DB and I'm using the SQL Import and Export Wizard in SQL Management Studio.

It almost works, but I get an error:

`Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again.`

This makes no sense, as I have clustered indexes on all my tables. I did see this Q&A on SO but if I switched to **.Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer** I get a different error:

`Cannot get the supported data types from the`, which is the very problem that A is supposed to solve.

Comment: What is the definition of the table that is failing?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using some other tool such as SqlAzureMW (http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) or RedGate's tools because the Import and Export wizard in Sql Management Studio is pretty much useless :-(

Also, take a look at some of the advices here:

[How to copy sql azure schema to another sql azure database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921254/how-to-copy-sql-azure-schema-to-another-sql-azure-database)